# Sentence comparison

Tags: sentence-choice

1. I'll take whatever **of that pie is left.**
2. I'll take whatever is **left of that pie.**

Do both of the above sentences mean the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst both sentences could be readily understood in context, the second sentence is more natural. The first sentence would seem to imply that 'left' is a property of the pie itself, and that you are requesting the section of pie which has this 'left property'.

The word **left** has many meanings in English -

As an adjective:

> Your left arm

As an adverb:

> Walk left until you reach the door.

As a noun:

> Drive straight, then take the next left.

But in the context of your examples, you are using *left* as the past participle of the verb **leave**, in the sense of referring to what remains.

Hence, you could alternatively write the phrase as:

> I'll take whatever remains of that pie.

Or, since the term *leftover* is specifically used to refer to an unconsumed food item -

> I'll take whatever is left over of that pie.